# Move parts of me to change me. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

- Move three of me west, and you get something that can hold text on a computer, or something that turns.
- Move one of me west, and one of me south-east, and you get something that can hold text on paper, or something that prevents turning, at least if you are picky.
- Move one of me west, and you get a troublemaker.
- Move one of me north-west, and you meet someone who might help you end up in the grave.
- Move one of me north-west, and you meet someone from Sweden's past.
- Move one of me north-west, and one of me south-east, and you might get a hunch that this is someone from France.
- Move one of me west, and one of me north-west, and you get something you may want to avoid eating, unless you want to become me.
- Move three of me, east, south-east, and south-west, respectively, to get something that's essential for making the previous thing.

What am I?

Hint:

> QWERTY

Correction: One of the hints used to say "Move one of me south-west, and you meet someone from Sweden's past." which was a typo that has now been fixed in the text above.

Comment: Suggestion for next hint: number of letters in the word.

Comment: The first hint was already very well clued by the absence of straight north and south moves.  I just couldn't figure out the words.

Comment: @humn Hmm, yeah, I was unsure whether people were confused by the mechanics of the riddle, which is why I dropped that hint. Would you suggest dropping another hint now or wait another week or so?

Comment: No rush in my opinion for the next hint, @nitro2k01, I'm continually amazed by others' word association abilities and trust the first hint to help reduce their search spaces

Comment: Sweden clue should be **north**-west, shouldn't it?

Comment: @shoover You are absolutely right. That was a mistake on my end.

Comment: It just occurred to me ... I wonder if you could make the clues rhyme?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Hint

The thing that helped me the most was

> realizing that the moves do not have to be to a contiguous key, but can skip several keys and merely indicate the general direction.

### Complete answer

I am

> ```
>                                        q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>              BIGGER                     a  s  d  f [G] h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x  c  v [B] n  m
> ```

Move three of me west

> ```
>  Move IGG to UFF to get BUFFER,        q  w [E][R] t  y [U](i) o  p
>  a programming term or a device         a  s  d [F](g) h  j  k  l
>  to clean/strip floors.                  z  x  c  v [B] n  m
> ```

something that can hold text on a computer, or something that turns.

Move one of me west, and one of me south-east

> ```
>  Move G to D, AND G to N               q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>  to get BINDER                          a  s [D] f (g) h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x  c  v [B][N] m
> ```

something that can hold text on paper, or something that prevents turning, at least if you are picky.

Move one of me west

> ```
>                                        q  w [E][R] t  y [U](i) o  p
>  Move I to U to get BUGGER              a  s  d  f [G] h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x  c  v [B] n  m
> ```

a troublemaker.

Move one of me north-west

> ```
>                                        q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>  Move B to D to get DIGGER              a  s [D] f [G] h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x  c  v (b) n  m
> ```

someone who might help you end up in the grave.

Move one of me south-west

> ```
>  Move G to R to get BIRGER,            q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>  if this should be north-west           a  s  d  f [G] h  j  k  l
>  instead of south-west!                  z  x  c  v [B] n  m
> ```

someone from Sweden's past.

Move one of me north-west, and one of me south-east

> ```
>  Move B to R and G to N                q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>  to get RINGER, as in                   a  s  d  f [G] h  j  k  l
>  Quasimodo the hunchback                 z  x  c  v (b)[N] m
> ```

someone from France.

Move one of me west, and one of me north-west

> ```
>  Move I to U and G to R to get         q  w [E][R] t  y [U](i) o  p
>  BURGER to avoid becoming BIGGER.       a  s  d  f [G] h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x  c  v [B] n  m
> ```

something you may want to avoid eating.

Move three of me, east, south-east, and south-west

> ```
>  Move B to M, G to N,                  q  w [E][R] t  y  u [I] o  p
>  and G to C to get MINCER.              a  s  d  f (g) h  j  k  l
>                                          z  x [C] v (b)[N][M]
> ```

something that's essential for making the previous thing.

Comment: Hurray! Which clues got you started? Also, mind if I add text-picture summaries of the moves?  (I was working on a worksheet text file that was only missing the correct words.) You can rollback or adjust them to your liking.

Comment: The thing holding text in a computer, I actually came up with first, but discarded it because of (hint that I'm about to add to the top of my answer). Likewise the ending up in a grave clue. The French person I knew where to go but had to pick around the various possibilities since at the time I didn't know how many letters were in the answer. I was actually quite puzzled until I realized (hint).

Comment: Please feel free to add the pictures!

Comment: Pictures added, shoover, allways rollback-able. I was really looking forward to seeing this solved.

Comment: Almost a perfect answer. :) The one little part of a clue you didn't fully explain was "at least if you are picky". That word is lock-picking terminology for a pin that prevents the core from turning because the pin is stuck, thus "if you are picky".